# Nested query in mysql, retrieve result dynamicly

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, hierarchical-data

I' trying to retrieve nested comments, I'm able to get all replies recursively for single commend by below code.

```
SELECT id, name, parent_id
FROM comments
WHERE id = 2
UNION
SELECT id, name, parent_id
FROM (SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id) sort,
     (SELECT @pv := 2) init
WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

Above query works but it only returns specific id. I want to retrieve all comments like saying `where post_id=1` but couldn't figure it out how we do it. I would be appreciate if anyone help.

**EDIT**: **I want to get all comments belongs to a post and their replies recursively.**

comments table has id,name,parent_id etc.. fields..

Comment: Sample data and desired results, please.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to get all comments belongs to a post and their replies recursively.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? It supports proper recursive queries, not the hackish solution you show. See docs and examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: Which `mySQL` version are you on @TeomanTıngır?

Comment: Hey @TeomanTıngır, does parent_id for reply comments only ? if that, then use simple get all the comments for a post `SELECT id, name, parent_id
FROM comments
WHERE id = 2`

Comment: @BillKarwin I know  v8 has pretty cool methods for recursive queries but my script running on a  shrared hosting which use 5.7

Comment: You might like this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/20860 I show a solution for storing tree-like data in MySQL 5.x that doesn't require nasty queries with variables and stuff. I also did a presentation: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data and I cover it in my book: https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns